# Why without 'that' or comma between 'chances are' 'it involves'? And why 'fall on'?

Tags: phrase-meaning, commas, optional-that

Why without comma or point between 'chances are' 'it involves'?

> But whichever side people **fall on** -- a big breakfast or small one --
>   **chances are it involves** a cup of coffee or tea.

Answer (score 2):

A comma would be OK there.

> But whichever side people fall on— a big breakfast or a small one—
>   chances are, it involves a cup of coffee or tea.

**chances are** is informal and conversational, as distinct from **the chances are**, which is in a slightly less colloquial register.  The reduced clause, omitting **that**, is in the same colloquial register.

**to fall**  there means "to happen to be".  Whichever side of the question people happen to be on...

The meaning is similar to the calendrical use of **fall**:

> This year, my birthday falls on a Sunday.

It happens to be on a Sunday.

Comment: Possibly a join word instead of a comma.  ...  chances are *that* it involves a ...